# Sorting of a calculated field fails when using report within a form in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report with some code to sort on a calculated column, so when the user clicks the label the report is sorted, here's the code:

```
Private Sub Label44_Click()

If Me.OrderBy = "IIf([SumOfCurrentPriceVol]<>0,([SumOfOfferedPriceVolume]-[SumOfCurrentPriceVol])/[SumOfCurrentPriceVol],0) DESC" Then
    Me.OrderBy = "IIf([SumOfCurrentPriceVol]<>0,([SumOfOfferedPriceVolume]-[SumOfCurrentPriceVol])/[SumOfCurrentPriceVol],0) ASC"
Else
    Me.OrderBy = "IIf([SumOfCurrentPriceVol]<>0,([SumOfOfferedPriceVolume]-[SumOfCurrentPriceVol])/[SumOfCurrentPriceVol],0) DESC"
End If

Me.OrderByOn = True
End Sub
```

When I use the report by itself it works fine. But If I put the report inside of a Form I get the following error message:

`"Run-Time Error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"`

at the

```
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

I tried changing the `Me` to `Report` and I get the same results. any idea of what may be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to re-create the issue. It's not with the complicated calculation which you may want to add to the recordsource. I re-created it with a simple sort of a single field. Here's what I found:

(Sorry I don't seem to be able to upload images here; which is unfortunate)

Check your report properties' [Data] tab and see `Order By On Load`. It's probably set to Yes. That means that you don't need to turn it On, because it's already on.

But at the same time, the default value for `OrderBy` is Null. The report will tell you that `OrderByOn = False` if there's a null value in OrderBy, despite the fact that `Order By On Load` is true!

So basically, you need to set a default `OrderBy` in the Properties, set a default `OderBy` in the `Report_Activate()` event, or update your code to look for a/the one time null value.

Why your given code works in report, but not subreport is a mystery; maybe a bug. I was able to resolve the issue by doing any one of the 3 suggestions above.

Oh, and don't forget to remove the `Me.OrderByOn = True` because that is what's causing the issue...some sort of half baked read-only error only triggered in a subreport.